Error 401 on GET method, 401 (Unauthorized)
I'm making a request to AccuWeather's public API, first there was a problem with cors but I solved it, now it's giving me an authorization error, what do I do?
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Citydata.css';

const Citydata = ({ cidade }) => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState(null);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const apiKey = 'ot0AvyzmQ1AkK3Z6c4BGzj7OAUwMRlIy'; // Substitua pela sua chave de API
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const getLocation = (city) => {
        const url = `/locations/v1/cities/search?apikey=${apiKey}&q=${city}`;

        fetch(url)
          .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
              throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
            }
            return response.json(); // Chama o método json() corretamente
          })
          .then(data => {
            setLocation(data);
            setError(null);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.error('Erro ao buscar localização:', err);
            setError('Não foi possível buscar a localização.');
            setLocation(null);
          });
      };
  
      if (cidade) {
        getLocation(cidade);
      }
    }, [cidade, apiKey]);

}

export default Citydata;

this is a get method API, what do I do ?

You never request an actual web resource. You call fetch(url) but url is a path without a host domain.

According to Accuweather documentation the base url is  https://dataservice.accuweather.com/. To address the issue in my previous comment, you need to prepend your URL path with that base URL. Aside from that, if you still receive 401 Unauthorized then you should double check your API key to ensure it is valid. I assume it is not actually ot0AvyzmQ1AkK3Z6c4BGzj7OAUwMRlIy as you would then be publicly sharing an API key which is a security concern.

already deleted the app which had this apiKey, I just posted here to make an example, thank you so much for the help!!
